# Error file not generated with log4j

Tags: java, gradle, log4j

I am running a gradle project and I an trying to have log4j both log to the console as well as to a file. While the error is logged to the console, no file is logged to. I have my log4j.properties in the src/main/resources. I have tried moving the properties files to the src folder as well as to just about every folder suggested on SO without success. I have tried both rollingFile and File within the log4j as well. Is there something wrong with by log4j.properties file, or am I not placing the file in the correct spot?

Here are my current files

log4j.properties

```
# root level configurations
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,console,rollingFile

# configuration for console outputs
 log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
 log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# configuration for file output (into a file named messages.log)
log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=/home/cbolles/devel/testing/gradle_testing/messages.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.8.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.8.2'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.18'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

task(runSimple, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.bolles.ErrorTester'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    args 'mrhaki'
    systemProperty 'simple.message', 'Hello '
}

defaultTasks 'runSimple'
```

LogTesting.java

```
package com.bolles;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class LogTesting
{

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(LogTesting.class);

    public static void reportError(Exception e, boolean consoleLog)
    {
        String errorMessage = "";
        if(e.getMessage() != null)
        {
            errorMessage = e.getMessage();
        }

        StringWriter stackTraceWriter = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace( new PrintWriter(stackTraceWriter));
        String stackTrace = stackTraceWriter.toString();

        log.error(errorMessage);
        log.log(Level.ERROR, errorMessage + "\n" + stackTrace);
    }
}
```

ErrorTester.java

```
package com.bolles;
public class ErrorTester 
{

    public static void nullStringTest()
    {
        String errorString = null;
        try
        {
            System.out.print(errorString);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            LogTesting.reportError(e, true);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        nullStringTest();
    }
}
```

None of the other answers seem to work for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The apparent problem seems to be that you are using log4j's LogManager and Logger classes. Make the following changes to your LogTesting class (slf4j is already among your dependencies as I see)

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogTesting.class);
...
log.error(errorMessage);
//log.log(Level.ERROR, errorMessage + "\n" + stackTrace); //no such method in slf4j
```

and it should write the error in the file too as expected.

(also you seem to need to modify the ErrorTester class because currently there is no exception thrown from there so LogTesting.reportError() is not called)